# HTML Formatting settings in VS-Code - Always wrap in new line

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting, format, settings

I tried finding a solution or setting for this. However, I cannot find anything related to it. Is it even possible to change the build in html formatter to the following:

**VS Code does it like this:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">View</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">Edit</button>
```

**How I want it:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
   View
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary">
   Edit
</button>
```

Basically I want the text always displayed in a new line for easier editing.

Comment: Are you looking for a formatter that allows the format you described? Or a formatter that will format your code to the format you described?

Comment: I try to tweak the settings so VS-Code knows that I want text in a separate line.

Comment: VSCode's isn't the best, most people will tell you prettier is, but prettier is opinionated, so you can't change the settings very much. Personally I format HTML & CSS myself, and turn all other formatting for it off. VSCode will allow you to put your tag on a separate-line, however, VSCode isn't going to do it for you, Prettier also allows you to put the tag on a separate-line, but once again it won't do it for you. I'm sure there's some 3rd party software somewhere that lets you do this, but you'll have to google it and read about like everyone else.

Comment: I really don't like prettier - yea. Guess I have to format myself then too. Couldn't find a third party software that does this - which is why I asked for help. Anyhow, thanks for getting back.

Comment: When you get use to formatting your own HTML its actually not that bad.